# how to fix 'DocumentApp isn't defined' in googleappmaker

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

In my GoogleAppMaker code, I've copied and pasted this sample from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs.

```
function createDoc() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals'], ['Ficus', 'Goat'], ['Basil', 'Cat'], ['Moss', 'Frog']];
  body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
      .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> DocumentApp isn't defined.

I thought I had defined it here:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Did you create this Apps Script file using the `Tools > Script Editor` button from the Google Doc User interface? In order to use `DocumentApp` the script needs to be bound to a document file.

Comment: thank you Rafa for this information , i used it in a scipt bound to ggldoc, and it work , but i can't use this function with an onclick() method in my application AppMaker ?

Comment: Check the documentation for the `onClick()` functionality at https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic. `onClick()` is "available on button, link, and other clickable widgets." though this might be better posed as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer Rafa , your help has been effective :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix. You are using the code in the wrong location. In AppMaker there is client script and server script. You are getting that error because you are using it in the client script; Instead, please use that code in a server script.

To learn more about server and client scripting with Google App Maker please see the official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dialog with a Page Fragment and put a button on the Page Fragment and connect the onClick to a Javascript function which then calls the server side function via google.script.run.  But you can't call the server side function directly from the Page Fragment.